# JQuery Setting Div Style After Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I think the position for `.flagPoint` is being set after the jquery effect takes place. I am new to jquery and was wondering if anyone can point out why the div styles are set after the effect runs?

The `.flagPoint` div does set itself correctly. It has to jump into position for the `bounce` effect.  *Works fine if I comment out the `bounce` effect
On Firefox 26.0 and IE 11

You can find my example here: 
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pN69D/1/)

CSS:

```
.pointerFlag
{
    width:auto;
    margin:auto;
    float:left;
}
.flagBox
{
    width:auto;
    background:LightGray;
    height:30px;
    float:right;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #888888;  
}
.flagPoint
{
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    border-top: 15px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid LightGray;
    float:right;
}
```

javascript:

```
function showBalance() {

    $("#divBalanceFlag").show("slide", {
        direction: "left"
    }, 150).delay(20);
    $("#divBalanceFlag").effect('bounce', {
        times: 2,
        distance: 10,
        direction: 'right'
    }, 350).delay(50);
}

function hideBalance() {
    $("#divBalanceFlag").hide("slide", {
        direction: "left"
    }, 150);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#divBalanceFlag").hide();

});
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="position:absolute;">

            <div id="divBalanceFlag" class="pointerFlag" style="position:relative; z-index:100; bottom:0px;">

                <div class="flagBox"> <span runat="server" id="accountBalanceSpan" style=" line-height:30px; color:#535353; padding-left:5px; padding-right:10px; font-size:medium; font-weight:bold; "> Your Balance is: $11</span> 
                </div>

                <div class="flagPoint"></div>

            </div>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br /> <br />
<button onclick="showBalance();"> Show </button>
<button onclick="hideBalance();"> Hide </button>
```

Thanks

Comment: The animation seems to be fine to me

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: Looks VERY nice - IE11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have removed the float from your flagBox and added a 10px margin-left, this is the necessary space for the pointer. and in the pointer i've added this css:

```
position:absolute;
left:0;
bottom:0;
```

See fiddle here.
[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pN69D/13/)

just a little fix to prevent line-breaking on the span text

```
.flagBox span { white-space: nowrap;}
```

Comment: haha awesome I was just about to add the `white-space: nowrap` to your answer. This worked perfectly! Thank you!